# How can the US cyclist federation take Lance Armstrong French Titles?

Tags: cycling, tour-de-france, doping

According to the news, the US Cyclist federation, had withdrawn all titles from Lance Armstrong.

How can a US organization take French Titles?  Or I am missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [USADA](http://www.usantidoping.org/), the United States Anti-Doping Agency, is the organization that determined that Lance Armstrong is guilty of doping during his career. <sub>[(1)](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/cycling/2012/10/10/lance-armstrong-usada-reasoned-decision-teammates-doping/1624551/) [(2)](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/sports/!invesitgations%20and%20enterprise%20docs/armstrong-reasoned-decision.pdf)</sub>

The [UCI](http://www.uci.ch/), the Union Cycliste Internationale (International Cycling Union) - the **world** governing body for the sport of cycling, agreed with the evidence the USADA had released. <sub>[(3)](http://espn.go.com/olympics/cycling/story/_/id/8536389/uci-agrees-strip-lance-armstrong-7-tour-de-france-titles)</sub>

Therefore, the **UCI**, not USA Cycling, is responsible for stripping Lance Armstrong of his Tour de France titles.

**IN ADDITION:** Reports on 14 January 2013 state that Lance Armstrong has admitted <sub>[(4)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akRHUsHnQZo) [(5)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cKBVPMotBA)</sub> to doping.

Comment: It is also UCI that decides whether a different winner will be announced, not the organizer ASO.

Comment: @Bernhard my understanding (at least the way the news was read) was that the Tour made that decision not UCI *or* ASO.

Comment: @waxeagle ASO=Tour+other events. But ASO wants the 7 years to be blank, but that's not 'official'